# Was Ishmael a Gentile?

Tags: gentiles, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I was wondering whether Ishmael was a Gentile, because that would seem to mean that an animal slaughtered by him would be non Kosher.

Comment: opposite http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9042/759

Comment: Particularly helpful is this particular answer to the question that @DoubleAA linked to: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9976/1713

Comment: @Daniel thanks a lot for the pointer , the answer is rather disrespectful and only his own personal views Jim Thio has rebuked him for harboring such intention and judging the prophets as evil after 1000s of years. Who are we to judge their natures?

Comment: Ali, Esau and Ishmael were not prophets. That answer links to a sources (so it's not only the answerer's views). This is not the place to discuss that answer: if you can recommend an edit to it, then comment there. And I use [the Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma).

Comment: if we can't say that Abraham was a Jew, because the word didn't exist, then how can we say anyone was a Gentile (meaning a non-Jew)? You can't be a "not" of a thing that doesn't exist, can you?

Comment: There was no such thing as Kosher then.

Comment: @Dan The word "Jew" is semantics. The word not being coined yet does not exclude the possibility of a distinct category of people.

Comment: @SethJ Perhaps there was no _obligation_ yet to keep Kosher, but there still could be "such a thing" as Kosher.

Comment: @Michoel I don't particularly feel like playing these games anymore with Ali. I don't much care to start with you or anyone else, either. No offense.

Answer (score 8):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe ([Likkutey Sichos vol. 15 pg. 192](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14933&st=&pgnum=205) and footnote 12-13 there) asserts that (unlike Eisav who the Gemora [calls](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9044/1535) an apostate Jew), Yishmael did not have the legal status of a Jew. He cites the view of many commentators, that only "in Yitzchok will be called your seed" (Genesis 21:12), whereas Yishmael was not considered the seed of Avraham and was disinherited (verse 10 there: "Drive out this handmaid and her son, for the son of this handmaid shall not inherit with my son, with Isaac"). For further elaboration he references to a lengthier discussion on the topic of whether Yishmael was considered Jewish in "Beis Ha'otzar" ([Rabbi Yosef Engel](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C), Klal Aleph [Ois Gimmel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20921&st=&pgnum=5) and [Ois Yud Ches](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20921&st=&pgnum=22)).

Two verses later, God said to Abraham, "Be not displeased concerning the lad and concerning your handmaid; whatever Sarah tells you, hearken to her voice, for in Isaac will be called your seed."

Comment: This verse was said by the jealous(God forbid) wife of  Abraham and not GOD : (verse 10 there: "Drive out this handmaid and her son, for the son of this handmaid shall not inherit with my son, with Isaac").

Comment: @Ali: Two verses later, G-d acknowledges that Sarah's words are prophetic and true: And God said to Abraham, "Be not displeased concerning the lad and concerning your handmaid; whatever Sarah tells you, hearken to her voice, for in Isaac will be called your seed."

Comment: @Michoel Well, He just to follow them. Not that they are "prophetic and true".

Comment: Isn't there a distinction between "seed" and "children"? I heard a Rabbi say that Jews are the seed of Avraham and gerim are children of Avraham. I'm not 100% clear on what that meant.

Answer (score 6):

[Everyone was a gentile then.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8674) So, yes, his slaughtered animals would not meet the standards of what we call "kosher". But don't worry: no one around at that time was required to eat only kosher.

Comment: It's actually not at all simple whether before Matan Torah Jews had the legal status of *bnei noach* or were considered Jewish. See the Perashas Derachim ([Derech Ha'asarim Drush Aleph](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%90)) at length who brings many opinions in the rishonim on this. In fact, the Bnei Yissachar (in one of his maamarim for Shabbas Hagadol) suggests that this was actually a machlokes between Yosef and his brothers.

Comment: @Michoel, see also the other answers to the question one of whose answers I linked to here.

Comment: @msh210 I was not referring to the semantics of the term "Jewish" but to the halachic status of Torah observant people pre-Matan Torah. Although the *avos* kept mitzvos, there is a discussion whether this was just "lechumrah" or they were actually considered no longer "bnei noach". This would make a difference in cases when it would be a *kulah* to keep mitzvos - for example, were they permitted to keep Shabbos? Eat meat that had been slaughtered but still twitches etc.

Comment: [cont.] According to the opinion that they were fully fledged Jews, there would certainly be a difference between their shechitah and that of a gentile.

Comment: @Michoel Why do we only have to choose between those two statuses? (Plus I'm sure you are aware that the extent the Avos kept mitzvos is a [large machlokes Rishonim and Amoraim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12091/759).)

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure where you are headed; what other statuses could there be?

Comment: Interesting question (that the Lubavitcher Rebbe discusses at length): could the Jews after Matan Torah eat the meat which they had shechted prior? Did they have to toivel their dishes? etc..

Comment: @Michoel Any other status we want to make up. The Torah wasn't given yet. Perhaps there were other possible statuses only applicable then, such as: pre-Jew==not obligated in mitzvot but allowed to keep shabbat. Something like that.

Comment: ...or not obligated, but had good Shehitah. Ping @doubleaa

Comment: Ping @Michoel...

Comment: The "kosher" of the time for all was ever min hachai

Comment: @Michoel, according to Nedarim, Avraham merited to no longer be called bnei Noach. This seems to apply only to bnei Yisrael, but not sure.