# Do Rabbis have to be Jewish by ethnicity?

Tags: rabbis, conversion-to-judaism

I am under the impression that a person can be received into Judaism from a gentile nation. My question is whether or not that person could conceivably then become a Rabbi?

Please indicate whether your answer has always been the case, or whether this (non/) requirement has always been consistent within Judaism.

Comment: The concept of a "rabbi" in the modern sense has not always existed within Judaism.

Comment: Hi Jas 3.1 welcome to Mi Yodeya! You might want to check out other questions in our tag [tag:gerut-conversion]. Hope to see you around :)

Comment: is an anecdotal answer useful? I know a convert who is a rabbi.

Comment: Related: [Can a convert become a synagogue president? Why or why not?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/can-a-convert-become-a-synagogue-president-why-or-why-not)

Comment: Ben bag bag and Ben hei hei (possibly the same person) were converts and tanoyim

Comment: Rabbi Asher meza is a convert and he is better than most rabbis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Shemaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%27maya_%28Mishnah%29) and [Avtalyon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avtalyon), two great rabbis from the 1st century BCE, are identified in the Talmud (Gittin 57b) as converts. So it seems that converts can become rabbis, and even important ones. I know of no sources that imply the law on this matter was different before that point.

See also this question: [Can a convert be a prophet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23516/can-a-convert-be-a-prophet)

Comment: +1 Weren't they also the leaders of their generation and the keepers of the Tradition (for lack of a better term)? Slightly more than one's average rabbi.

Comment: I said *great* rabbis

Comment: The Gemera says they were descendants of Gerim. 
מבני בניו של סנחריב למדו תורה ברבים מאן אינון שמעיה ואבטליון היינו

Since they led the sanhedrin, they couldn't have been gerim themselves. A modern-day rabbi is a separate question though.

Comment: This answer ignores the halakhic problem of כל משימות שאתה משים לא יהו אלא מקרב אחיך (Kiddushin 76b, Yevamos 45b). For a teshuvah on this question, see e.g., שו"ת אגרות משה יורה דעה חלק ד סימן כו

Comment: @ArielK _Mea culpa_! I didn't pay close enough attention, conflating the issue of converts descendants with themselves probably primed by the Wikipedia page which says they were actual converts. I don't know if this still answers the question well; it depends what he means by "Jewish by ethnicity", although I think my conclusion is pretty much on target.

Comment: @wfb I ignored it on purpose, not thinking it was particularly relevant to someone's becoming a rabbi.

Comment: 1. It is quite relevant, as the halakhic literature about this question attests. 2. Even if there would be no problem of a ger being a rabbi, Shmayah & Avtalyon would be a problem of a ger being members (& heads of) the Sanhedrin--this problem was already raised by the Tosfos Yom tov. How then can you cite them as precedent without noting the problem?

Comment: @wfb 1. Which halachik literature? 2. See my above comments.

Comment: Did you see the R. Moshe I quoted?

Comment: @wfb Yes. He's talking about a position of leadership (like Rosh Yeshiva), ie a political/legal/bureaucratic position, not a rabbi (even taking modern semicha as a _heter hora'ah_).

Comment: As R. Noson Gestetner points out in his article on this question, the word רבנות means שררה http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50287&st=&pgnum=131&hilite=

Comment: @wfb So a ger can't own a slave, because a slave owner is called "Rav"???

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no issur שררה over עבדים. However, you probably cannot appoint a גר as the רב over your Jewish workers.

Comment: Shemaya and Avtalyon do not help answer whether a ger can be a rabbi, since they were not gerim themselves. (See the second paragraph of wikipedia. C.f. the 'source' for first paragraph.) However, one could probably argue that many modern shul rabbis are not positions of serarah, and therefore a ger can become a rabbi nowadays. And obviously a ger can write/compile a commentary/translation on the Torah.

Comment: @wfb I wasn't suggesting there would be an issue with slaves. What I am suggesting is that the etymology of the word is irrelevant, so don't 'prove' to me that it's assur because Rav comes from lashon Serarah.

Comment: OK, so maybe your answer should acknowledge that it may depend on the role of the rabbi and whether he has authority? Especially since the question asks for changes over time, and rabbis in the past had real authority. Also, maybe consider updating the info about Shmaya & Avtalyon

Comment: @ArielK Ritva and Meiri on Yoma 71b say they themselves were Gerim, as does Rambam and Bartenura to Eduyos 5:6.

Comment: Mea culpa, there are such opinions. However, it is very difficult, since a ger cannot be a Nasi according to all opinions. Its much simpler to say they were descendants of gerim. See Maharal "אבל יש שפירשו כי הם עצמם גרים היו בודאי זה טעות גמור". Otherwise, there case was an exception to the rule which cannot be applied in other cases (See Igros Moshe).

Comment: To the extent that a rabbi is a leader of a community, there is an argument that a convert should not be a shul rabbi just as there are opinions that a convert cannot become a shul president.  See [Can a convert become a synagogue president? Why or why not?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/can-a-convert-become-a-synagogue-president-why-or-why-not).  But the same counter-argument is applicable -- if the congregation agrees to accept a convert over them, then the ruling does not apply.  See my answer to the cited question.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/can-a-convert-become-a-synagogue-president-why-or-why-not

Comment: @DoubleAA There are a lot of details. First, Dine Mamonot or Dine Nefashot, secondly, to be Dayan for other Gerim or for Israel, third, to be occasionally Dayan or attitred Dayan. Moreover, there are multiple opinions in Rishonim, Rashi, Tosfot, Rif etc...

Answer (score 9):

Although there is no problem with a convert being a great Torah scholar, as the examples of Shmayah and Avtalyon as well as Onkelos ha-Ger and many others amply demonstrate, there may be a problem with appointing a convert as the rabbi of a community. This question is addressed directly by [R. Nosson Gestetner](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50287&st=&pgnum=131&hilite=), who [concludes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50287&st=&pgnum=136) that a convert cannot receive the title "Rav" although he may be the one to whom the community turns to answer their questions.

This issue was also addressed by R. Herschel Schachter, in a [responsum about women rabbis](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2011%20Schachter.pdf). Rabbi Schachter cites Rema (Yoreh De'ah, end of siman 245) and Gra (Yoreh De'ah 245:38) that being the rabbi of a city is a position of *serarah*. This would mean that it would not be permitted for a convert. In the words of Rabbi Schachter:

> Based on the interpretation of the Torah *she’Be’al Peh*, the *pesukim*
> tell us that we may not appoint a *ger* to serve as King or in any
> capacity of *serarah*, as, for example, to serve as a rabbi of a
> community, or (as mentioned by the Talmud) as president of a labor
> union. A *ger* may not serve as a *dayan* in a *din Torah* involving a
> Yisrael, but may serve as a *dayan* in a *din Torah* involving other
> *geirim*. Obviously it is possible to confer *semichah* on a *ger*,
> otherwise he would not even be able to serve as a *dayan* for a case
> involving other *geirim*. Although a *ger* may not serve as a rabbi in a
> kehillah of Yisraelim, we still allow *geirim* to join the *semichah*
> program in the Yeshiva and to receive *semichah* upon successful
> completion of their studies, because years ago real *semichah* was
> sometimes conferred on *geirim*.

R. Moshe Feinstein does not address this exact question. Nevertheless, in addressing a similar question about whether a convert can become a Rosh Yeshiva, he expresses a lenient inclination. Here is a free translation of what R. Moshe Feinstein says  ([Iggeros Moshe YD 4:26](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14679&pgnum=257)):

> The simple answer, based on the Gemara in Kiddushin 76b... and Yevamot
> 45b... and the Rambam Hil. Melachim 1:4... is that it is forbidden to
> appoint a convert for a position of authority for Jews... But you [the
> questioner] wanted to prove based on Shmayah and Avtalyon and others
> [that it is permitted]--however, besides for the fact that we don't
> know exactly what their lineage was [whether their mother was a born
> Jew], one cannot bring a proof from them because they were the
> greatest of their time...and who knows if it was not a temporary
> exception [hora'at sha'ah], like the case of the prophet Devorah who
> was a judge (see Tosafos Bava Kama 15a...and Yevamot 45b...) and how
> can we compare our case to theirs.
>
> But practically, one must know
> that the commandment to love the convert (Deut. 10:19) obligates us to
> bring them close, and to be lenient in all these types of issues.
> Therefore, after much consideration, it seems that we only consider [forbidden]
> appointments in our time to be those that have [real] authority, but
> the role of a Rosh Yeshiva is to teach students who want to learn...

See also R. Moshe Sternbuch, Teshuvot ve-Hanhagot 3:305.

> נשאלתי אם גר יכול להיות ר"מ בישיבה, ונראה שמותר, שעיקר האיסור הוא
> בשררה דוקא, אבל ר"מ בישיבה אינו שררה ולא מוריש לבניו אלא ממנים אותו
> כפי חכמתו ויראתו, ולא דמי למלך ושאר שררות שעיקרם כיבוד וגם מורישים
> אותם. ומיהו יש דעות שלא מחלקים כסברא דשררה הנ"ל אלא בכל גווני אסור,
> ומיהו נראה דהיינו לשמש כראש ישיבה אבל כמגיד שיעור ללמד לתלמידים אין
> לחשוש.
>
> ולענין להיות "רב", שבזמננו שמלבד תפקידו להורות יש לו גם
> תפקידים שונים לנהל כעין שררה, ראוי להחמיר ולא ליקח גר לתפקידים אלו
> כשיש לפנינו יהודי אחר ראוי כמוהו. ולדעת האחרונים יש היום ירושה ברבנות
> שעיקרה שררה, ולכן לדעתי ראוי להעמיד אדם אחר שישא תואר "הרב" לכבוד,
> והגר שהוא הראוי לכך בפועל הוא ישמש בתפקידי הוראת ההלכה למעשה, אף
> שמכונה "מורה צדק" ואפילו סגן וכה"ג ודאי שרי, ומתקיים בו אהב את המלאכה
> דרבנות ושנא את הרבנות עצמה ושכרו רב. וכאשר מסרבים לגרים למנותם יש
> להסביר להם שמגדולי ישראל היו גרים וצאצאיהם, עיין ברמב"ם בפתיחה, ולא
> מפני פחיתותם לא מקבלים אותם, אלא שדין תורה הוא ... ואין להם לראות שום פחיתות בכך, וכמו שישראלים לא ראויים
> לשמש בכהונה רק מזרע אהרן, ומ"מ כשזוכים לכתר תורה גדול יותר מכתר כהונה,
> וכתר התורה אינו שייך לשררות שבה

R. Elyashiv (He'arot, Kiddushin 76b) writes as follows:

> נסתפקתי אם יכולין למנות גר לראש ישיבה. והנה אם ממנין אותו רק על הגדת
> שיעורים נראה בסברא דזה לא נחשב מינוי של שררה. וקצת ראיה לזה, דהרי איתא
> דגר יכול להיות שליח צבור בתפלה, אך זה אינו ראיה כ"כ דיש לדחות דאיירי
> בש"ץ באקראי בעלמא ולא בקביעות. אך עכ"פ נראה בסברא דהן מינוי לש"ץ
> בקביעות, והן מינוי להגדת שיעורים א"ז נחשב בכלל מינוי שררה על הצבור. אך
> מה שיש לדון זהו לענין למנותו ראש ישיבה, שכל ענייני הישיבה נחתכים על
> פיו, דאפשר דזה נחשב למינוי שררה על הצבור.

R. Asher Weiss, Minchat Asher, Bereishit siman 71, concludes:

> העולה מכל הנ"ל דגר צדק ראוי הוא לכהן כדיין (בקיבלוהו עליהם) ומורה צדק,
> ואף לרבנות נראה לכאורה דיש מקום להתיר מדעת הקהל.

See also R. Yonah Reiss, Kanfei Yonah, pp. 135-136, citing R. Soloveitchik.

Comment: This is interesting information, but I don't understand what your answer is.

Comment: The answer is it's complicated

Comment: Are you  sure you got that reference right? Gra 245:38 discusses inheriting a position from one's father.

Comment: Anyone else find it funny that R Schacher is basing his argument on R Shaul Lieberman?

Comment: Yes, that is what R. Schachter quotes. The Gra quotes the Sifrei and Tosefta in Shekalim which learns from the pasuk הוא ובניו בקרב ישראל (about kings) to all "parnasei yisrael," applies it to communal rabbis, and says that כל הקודם לנחלה קודם לשררה applies to communal rabbis.

Comment: (And as for your other comment, I think he meant it to be funny--as in even the leader of Conservative Judaism thought this was unacceptable. The geirim part is independent of Lieberman.)

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget Unkelos - another Sage who was a convert. His translation of the Torah is found in every Observant Jewish home.

Nowadays, I know of several prominent rabbis who are converts, but I will not name them here for fear of lashon hara.

In other words, there is absolutely no impediment to a convert becoming a rabbi or Jewish leader.

Comment: Hey Naomi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this answer! I'm not sure I agree that naming someone as a convert is lashon hara (else surely the Talmud wouldn't have). That being said, I don't think it's necessary either. Either way, welcome, and I hope to see you around the site!

Comment: @HodofHod, I don't think it's lashon hara, but we are forbidden (citation needed) to ask someone if he's a convert because of "reminding him of his (idolatrous?) past", so I would think that publicly naming a convert as such would be the same problem.  (Obviously sometimes it *does* happen or we wouldn't know about Onkelos, Shemaya, and Avtalyon, but I sure don't know how to decide when it's ok.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Definitely "citation needed"( for it being "forbidden ... to ask someone if he's a convert")! I was unaware such a _Halakhah_ exists, and still don't think it does.

Comment: @TamirEvan, it's something I was taught (as part of leadership/outreach/etc training), but I don't know where it comes from.  And obviously there are "need to know" exceptions (e.g. marriage involving a kohein), but I understand it to be a general "don't talk about it".  Maybe after Shabbat I'll go digging.

Comment: @TamirEvan on the other hand, [why wait](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27885/472)?

Answer (score 1):

A Rabbi has several functions, regarding the Rabbi who judge people, see below.

Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat 7.1

> מי ראוי לדון והפסולים מחמת שנאה וקורבה ובו י"ב סעיפים: ב"ד של ג' שהיה אחד מהם גר ה"ז פסול לדון לישראל אא"כ היתה אמו (או אביו) (מרדכי בשם תוס' פ"ב מ"ח) מישראל וגר דן את חבירו הגר אע"פ שאין אמו מישראל (וע' בי"ד סי' רס"ט):
> A Court of three [Judges] of which one was a proselyte is unfit to judge a fellow Israelite unless his mother or his father were Israelitish. A proselyte may, however, judge his fellow proselyte although his mother is not an Israelitish woman.

Comment of the Urim Vetumim (Urim)

> הרי זה פסול לדון לישראל.  בכה"ג האריך דאיך היו שמעיה ואבטליון שלפי דעת רמב"ם בהקדמתו לספר מדע היו גרים גמורים וכן משמע בעדיות דוגמ' השקוהו סנהדרין זה נשיא וזה אב"ד ומזה העלה דהצבור **קבלוהו עלי' לרוב חשיבות'** ובקבולהו עליה מותר ע"ש שהאריך ולפי דבריו צ"ל אם קבלוהו חשובי עדה אע"פ שאין רוב צבור מסכימים הוי כקבלוהו עליה ויכול לדון דאטו בשמעיה ואבטליון הסכימו רוב ישראל בכל מקומות א"י וח"ל זהו מהנמנע אלא הואיל והסכימו סנהדרין וראשי חכמים וכה"ג בימים ההם הוה כקבלוהו כל ישראל עליהם אלא שאני חוכך דכי מהני קבלוהו עליו בד"מ דהרי יכול להפקיר ממונו וליתנו למי שרוצה ואף הוא יכול לומר הריני מתרצה לכל מוצא פיך אם ליתן או למחול וכדומה אבל בד"נ שאין רשות ביד אדם לומר הרגוני וא"כ פשיטא דלא שייך בי' קבלה וכי יכול אדם לומר הריני מכשיר קרוב או פסול ואם יחייב ראשי להריג' יקטלוני זהו אין בידו וכל טיבו של ב"ד הגדול בירושלים לדון ד"נ דין זקן ממרא ודכותיה וד"מ לא היו דנין ממש כלל וא"כ עדיין הקושיא איך יהיה מקהל גרים ראשי סנהדרין. ולכן צ"ל או **דמלך שאני** כיון דרשות ביד מלך להמית ולהרוג לתקון מדינה כמ"ש הרמב"ם בהל' רוצח ע"ש אף הוא אם רואה אדם גדול בתורה ומדע **יכול למנותו לראש לדון אפי' ד"נ** כי אתו דבר חוק ומשפט וכן אמרו דריש גלותא יכול ליתן רשות אפי' למאן דלא גמיר וסביר כולי האי והכל מטעם חוק המלך כמ"ש הריב"ש עיין לעיל ס"ג וא"כ שמעי' ואבטליון נתמנו מפי מלך כי בימיהם היה מלכי חשמנאים הכשרים ויכולים לדון בכפי' כי יד המלך היה עמם או שנאמר כי באמת אלו היה בא דיני נפשות לא היו דנים ולא נתמנו לכך רק למקבלי שמועה ובירור הלכה בתורה שבע"פ לעוצם חכמתם ובינתם ויראתם הקודמת ובזו היו נשיאים ואב"ד ולא לדון דיני נפשות וצ"ע:‏

He says that Shemaya and Avtalion (about which @DoublaAA speaks in his answer) they were able to preside over the great court despite their status as converts because  were chosen by the king and he has the strength to impose them.

This subject is treated in Sanhédrin 36b, Kiddushin 76b, Yevamot 102a. Rashi holds that a convert can be a judge for civil law cases. The Chiddush of the Tumim is based on Rishonim, who try to solve the problem of what seems to be a contradiction between Gemara Sanhedrin 36b and Yevamot 102a. They say that a convert can be occasionally a judge or that he can be but that he cannot impose himself as a judge to settle conflicts, against the opinion of the stakeholders. For criminal laws, the Tumim said that the judge does not act at the request of people who are judged. And he provides an explanation that is an innovation, that the king, as he can give coercive power to judges (Sanhedrin 6a), he can give it to a convert, even for criminal affairs.